# Django Forms - How to Save multiple inputs(type=radio) with the same "name" attribute?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm currently working on a survey app. **I am using django forms**, however I find myself with the following problem:

If I only have one question there is no problem in saving the answers, but if there are several questions there is a problem because the template is rendered in the following way:

```
{% for question in questions %}

<div class="options">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a{{ forloop.counter }}"  value="A" />
    <label for="a{{ forloop.counter }}">Agree</label>    
</div>
<div class="options">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b{{ forloop.counter }}"  value="D" />
    <label for="b{{ forloop.counter }}">disagree</label>
</div>
```

So for example if I render 5 questions, the inputs of those 5 questions will have the same attribute name, so I can only choose one radiobutton, which logically is an error because I should be able to choose 5 (because they are 5 questions).

I could change the name of each group of radiobuttons according to the question to which I allude, and with that each group of radiobuttons would have different names, however if I do this I could not save them because according to my forms.py:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('answer' , )
```

Then to the being the names of the radiobuttons different to "answer" will generate error when saving the answers.

**How can I save the answer to several questions?**

**Clarification:** I want to render the form manually and not with {{ form.as_p }} because I will work with bootstrap and the form will have certain particularities at an aesthetic level.

Comment: This is all a bit strange. Why do you have radio buttons at all if you want to select multiple items? What is the `answer` field and does it permit multiple selections? Why are you rendering the fields manually?

Comment: @DanielRoseman may be a problem with the word item (my error), item=question. Each question has two answer choices.  For example question1: Healthy eating is worth -- options a) agree b) disagreement. question2: Exercise is worth --- options a) agree b) disagreement. I want to render the fields manually and not with {{ form.as_p }} because I'm going to work with bootstrap and aesthetically the way it's going to be rendered has certain peculiarities.